# Java dynamic binding vs. method matching. How are these methods matched/binded?

Tags: java, class, subclass

I have a question about the following code and its output:

```java
public class MoarTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Person p = new Student();
        Student s = new Student();
        
        p.m(0);     // Prints "Person method"
        p.m(0.0);   // Prints "Person method"
        
        s.m(0);     // Prints "Student method"
        s.m(0.0);   // Prints "Person method"
    }
}

class Person {
    public void m(double n) {
        System.out.println("Person method");
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public void m(int n) {
        System.out.println("Student method");
    }
}
```

The most confusing cases for me are `p.m(0)` and `s.m(0.0)`. In `p.m(0)` the method chosen is `m(double n)` even though the argument given was an integer, while in `s.m(0.0)` it matched the method to `m(double n)` even though there is a method in the Student class that can work the the given double arguement.

How does the type of the variable change which method is called? And how are the methods chosen?

Comment: The type of the variable, the `Person` or `Student` on the left side determine what methods are available and visible directly to the `main()` method to call.

Comment: Method signature/overload resolution happens at compile-time, using the static type of the value to left of the `.` (dot). Method override resolution happens at runtime, using the dynamic type of the actual value.

Comment: A nitpick, so not a answer but a comment, but it would be far easier to read the code if the names of the objects were `person` and `student` (or even `p` and `s`) than `A` and `B`. One because they are readable, and two java standards recommend that object names start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A.m(0)` chooses between the methods in the class `Person` as `A` is the type of `Person` (even though the actual object is of type `Student`, it is declared as a type Person, so that is used). Because the type of `A` (`Person`) does not have visibility into the child class methods, this is the only choice available which is the method with the `double` argument.

If there were an int method and a double method, the JVM would have chosen the `int` method. Actually this is exactly what happens when you call B.m(0). In this case, the JVM has two methods `m(int)` and `m(double`) and it chooses `m(int)`.

`B.m(0.0)` does not match with int as `0.0` is `double` and not an `int`

Comment: This is the case only for overloaded methods right?
In overridden methods the method is dynamically bond at runtime, and the search will start from the bottom.
Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking. If there were a method in Student with the signature `m(double)` then the call B.m(0.0) would call that than the parent method.